# DTO classes vs. struct

Tags: c#, struct, dto, n-tier-architecture

So, this is actually this question is my current keystone.
I'm working on refactoring of my personal project, trying increase performance, optimize memory usage, make code easy and clear. I have a different application layers (actually, DAL, BLL, ServiceAgents which is WCF services). I'm using Entities/Models/DTOs to pass data between those layers, which is stateless (don't have any logic at all). Currently they're objects like this:

```
public class Person
{
  public ComplexId Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  // ...
}
```

I used to use such approach, it's like a "best practice", is it? Is this best way to store transferred data? What if I change it for **struct** like this:

```
public struct Person
{
    public ComplexIdentifier ComplexId;
    public string Name;
}

public struct ComplexIdentifier
{
    public int LocalId;
    public int GlobalId;
}
```

Is this would be better way from performance/memory usage perspective? Or maybe there is some kind of traps acting that way?

Comment: "class" (that was an easy one ;p)

Comment: Thanks all for participating!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For standard DTO entities, you will want to stick with the class.

A `struct` has a much more *limited* range of potential use cases than classes. There are also efficiency issues when `struct` types get too large (don't forget, they are value types and are *copied* when passed around), as outlined in the [MSDN guidelines about value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y23b5415%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Not to mention **plenty** of gotchas when you start having `struct` types exposed through properties, or accidentally box it when referencing interfaces, or make them mutable...

I'm not [saying not to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil) `struct` when it is relevant, but I *very* rarely find myself needing to use `struct` types in our main desktop application - which is layered and features DTO types.

---

The performance issue cannot be answered as simply as `struct` vs. `class`. You will need to employ a profiling tool such as [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) or [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/) in order to find the hotspots and go from there. Performance issues are not trivial and good tooling is usually the start of the answer.

Comment: +1. One adition: [Mutable structs are EVIL!!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)

Comment: @Steven Of course, I've added that link in my answer - sort of subliminally ;-)

Comment: Agreed.  To alleviate some headaches surrounding copying values to and from these objects, leverage [AutoMapper](automapper.org).

Comment: Mutable classes used as data transfer objects are way more evil than mutable structs.

Answer (score 8):

> Is this would be better way from performance/memory usage perspective?

No. Structures are value types, so they're copied by value. This means that instead of copying just a reference, you will always copy the full object. If anything, it will probably be slightly slower and use more memory (since the object will duplicated).

Another reason why you should't do this: mutable structs should always be avoided, as they can cause unexpected behavior if you're not careful.

Comment: Since then, readonly structs have been introduced and passing by reference has been extended to return values and readonly reference parameters with the 'in' keyword.

Answer (score 7):

The two best choices for a data transfer object should generally be either a deeply-immutable class object, or a struct with exposed fields of types suitable for use as data transfer objects.  Other types of structs may sometimes be usable as well, but exposed-field structs are by far the simplest, and that simplicity is a great virtue.

The notion that mutable structs are evil dates back to some early C# compilers which in which

```
  SomeReadonlyStruct.SomeProperty = 5;
```

would be silently transformed by the compiler into:

```
  var temp = SomeReadonlyStruct;
  temp.SomeProperty = 5;
```

Hiding struct fields behind readonly properties was an attempt to ensure the former statement would refuse to compile instead of yielding broken code.  Since newer compilers will refuse to mutate writable fields of readonly structs, there's no longer any need to wrap fields in read-only properties.

Structs with exposed fields have a huge advantage compared with other types of data transfer objects: every struct which has exposed fields of types suitable for data-transfer and no other members else except perhaps a constructor behaves the same way, with no surprises.  Someone who has never used structs might be a little surprised by the fact that they don't act like classes, but someone who understands how any such struct works will understand how they all work.

Consider the following code:

```
  customerPhone = someDataSource.GetPhoneNumber(customerID);
  customerPhone.Extention = "5309"
```

Some people dislike the fact that if `customerPhone` is an exposed-field struct, setting the `Extension` property won't affect the information in `someDataSource`.  While it's certainly true that writing a struct field won't update anything else, that's a much better situation than would exist if `customerPhone` were a mutable class type.  Anyone who understands that `customerPhone` is an exposed-field struct type will know that changes to its members won't affect anything else.  By contrast, if `customerPhone` is a mutable class type, code like the above might update `someDataSource` by changing the phone number associated with that `customerID`.  Or it might not.  Or, if one phone number was associated with two `customerID` values, the above code might change both of them.  The amount of code one may have to study to determine exactly what effects and side effects the above code might have would be quite large.  Worse, it may be difficult to be sure that one hasn't missed anything.

There are definitely some places where passing around class object references can be more efficient than passing around structs.  There are also a few cases where mutable class objects can be useful data holders within a class.  Some generic wrappers, however, can faclitate wrapping a struct in a mutable or immutable class, *and exchanging the information between those types of classes*.

```
interface IReadableHolder<T> { T Value {get;} }

class MutableHolder<T> : IReadableHolder<T>
{
  public T Value;
  IReadableHolder.Value {get {return Value;} }
  public MutableHolder(T newValue) { Value = newValue; }
  public MutableHolder(IReadableHolder<T> it) { Value = it.Value; }
}
class ImmutableHolder<T> : IReadableHolder<T>
{
  T _Value;
  public Value {get {return _Value;} }
  public ImmutableHolder(T newValue) { _Value = newValue; }
}
```

Such a construct would be much more awkward without mutable structs.

Answer (score 2):

A `struct` may be more dangerous is that value types are handled much more differently by the `CLR` and if written poorly (e.g. a mutable struct) can create terrible headaches. *Also, if your type contains many fields and then is passed from method to method you will be copying every field's value on each method call* thus using more memory than if you had used a class in the first place.

The use of  [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transfer_Object) (data transfer objects) which would encourage the separation of state and behavior. This can be a good design if done properly (and in most cases you would implement this pattern using classes, not structs).

Furthermore, the specific case of using a `struct` as the `DTO object` seems flawed, because it introduces unnecessary `redundancy`. Since `structs cannot inherit other structs`, you can't express is-a relationships. What do you do when you have `Customer` which inherits from `Person`. Do you repeat all of the `Person properties in the Customer` struct? Do you nest a Person struct inside a Customer struct? Neither approach is ideal. If you at least used classes, **you could have Customer extend Person**.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the class approach, the struct approach could even be slower since structs are value types and copies will be made whereever you pass them as function parameters. So for your DTOs stick with the class aproach.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is: classes are better.

With classes you can implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface what will be very helpful if you do databinding.

You can also have some private fields like "ID" only with "get"-property,
you can add some methods to your class, you can make your entities serializable.
All I want to say, that you are more flexible with classes, and i don't think that there is any great performance difference between struct and classes in that case.

Here is a very nice book which helped me a lot by designing nTier-applications:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817644.aspx

Take a look there. It says:
"Choosing between structs and classes. For simple business entities that do not
contain hierarchical data or collections, consider defining a struct to represent
the business entity. For complex business entities, or for business entities that
require inheritance, define the entity as a class instead."

Comment: I'm use stateless classes - I know about INotifyPropertyChanged but according my task I don't need it. I also don't need add any logic (methods) to this objects. And get-only properties - struct can have readonly fields, can' it?

Comment: To add to this - a DTO is intended as a transferrable object between two systems. Why would you pollute it with Notification events and/or domain logic? It makes no sense as an argument "for" the use of classes in this instance. The OP specifically states "DTO" in the question.